# How to get the very first value from PickerView when it first pop up / when user not yet start any access

Tags: swift, getvalue, pickerview

I try to use this method `selectedRow(inComponent: 0)`, yet it doesn't work for me. Any way out to get the first/default value from picker when it is not active?

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return countries.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return countries[row].name
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       country.text = countries[row].name //`country.text` is just textField
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. You should show some code related to your question.

Comment: @nayem I'm sorry but now i updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not a big deal-**

Just define your picker view as global and access the value for `objectAtIndex(0)`

And write this line of code in `viewDidLoad()`

**Not exact, but something like this-**

```
@IBOutlet var yourPicker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

var yourArray = ["Apple", "Samsung", "Nokia"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourPicker.text = yourArray[0]
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for getting the first value, not setting it.

Comment: You can get/set whatever you want in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I'm working on textField. When I focus on textField the picker pop up. Then i want get the first value and set it to the textfield without user access.

Comment: Not getting you bro

Comment: @EKChhuon Are you looking for something like this https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's i'm looking for. Many thank!! @iDeveloper